# Corosync/Pacemaker + Haproxy Failed Actions: insufficient privileges

Tags: haproxy, pacemaker, corosync, lsb

I setup a Corosync/Pacemaker cluster + HAproxy using the following guide on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:
http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2012/04/15/active-passive-failover-cluster-on-a-mysql-galera-cluster-with-haproxy-lsb-agent/

I have not added the virtual ip setup, only two nodes, both with Haproxy installed on them. I am using the lsb:haproxy and my config is as follows:

[image: Corosync lsb:haproxy]
[image: failed actions: insuffient privileges]
To test everything, I kill the haproxy process by running the following command:
    sudo kill -9 [PID#]

I then check the status of my cluster and receive the following error message: "Failed actions: insufficient privileges". I did not change haproxy user/group definition and my aisexec{} is using root for both user and group.

What should my permissions be if I want Corosync/Pacemaker to manage Haproxy?

**EDIT:** When I run the below service stop command, haproxy restarts as expected. Checking `crm status` haproxy daemon is running like normal

```
# sudo service haproxy stop
# sudo crm status
HaproxyHA     (lsb:haproxy):    Started node1
Failed Actions:
```

But when I kill the pid manually, I keep seeing the error:

```
# sudo kill -9 $PID
HaproxyHA (lsb:haproxy): Started node1 (unmanaged) FAILED
Failed Actions:
```

After implementing change Federico mentioned `(/bin/kill $pid || return 7)` it doesn't change my problem and I find this in my logs:

```
pengine: warning: unpack_rsc_op: Processing failed op stop for HaproxyHA on node1: not running (7)
```

Comment: Check /var/log/haproxy.log if there is any message

Comment: Check the cluster log file for what exactly went wrong (look for messages from the haproxy resource). Probably one of the haproxy  directories or files has wrong permissions.

Comment: @FedericoSierra Corosync.log just emits: "Preventing HaproxyHA from restarting on node1: operation stop failed with insufficient privileges", but no actionable feedback.
Haproxy only logs start and stop statuses, nothing useful for me to modify in the config file

Comment: can you post your crm config?

Comment: @FedericoSierra the image above is all there is in my crm config. Just added the lsb:haproxy resource and nothing else.

Comment: You have set? `property stonith-enabled=false` and  `property no-quorum-policy=ignore`

Comment: @FedericoSierra yes those are both set to the values you mentioned

Comment: failover occurs? because messages may be normal in a situation of failure of one of the nodes

Comment: @FedericoSierra No failover occurs when killed manually, it keeps showing the [unmanaged) FAILED error when i run [crm status]. Also grepping for haproy in ps aux returns nothing. Only way to get haproxy running and back to normal is restart corosync/pacemaker services

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in the [init script](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-crmsh/html/Pacemaker_Explained/ap-lsb.html), it does not respect the [LSB spec](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html).

If you look at the function `haproxy_stop`, in file `/etc/init.d/haproxy`:

```
haproxy_stop()
{
    if [ ! -f $PIDFILE ] ; then
        # This is a success according to LSB
        return 0
    fi
    for pid in $(cat $PIDFILE) ; do
        /bin/kill $pid || return 4
    done
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    return 0
}
```

In particularly, the line `/bin/kill $pid || return 4`. This makes the case that the process is killed the return value is 4, which according to the spec this is: **user had insufficient privileges**. Which is not correct.

> In case of an error while processing any init-script action except for
>   status, the init script shall print an error message and exit with a
>   non-zero status code:
>
> ```
> 1 generic or unspecified error (current practice)
> 2 invalid or excess argument(s)
> 3 unimplemented feature (for example, "reload")
> 4 user had insufficient privilege
> 5 program is not installed
> 6 program is not configured
> 7 program is not running
> 8-99  reserved for future LSB use
> 100-149   reserved for distribution use
> 150-199   reserved for application use
> 200-254   reserved
> ```

You can try to change by:

```
/bin/kill $pid || return 7
```

the correct way is stop daemon with [killproc(8)](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/it/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=killproc) and if this fails `killproc` sets the return value according to LSB.

**Eg.**

```
/sbin/killproc -p $PIDFILE $HAPROXY
```

> sends the signal SIGTERM to the pid found in  `$PIDFILE` if  and only
>   if this pid belongs to $HAPROXY.  If the named  `$PIDFILE` does not
>   exist,  killproc  assumes  that  the daemon  of $HAPROXY is not
>   running.  The exit status is set to 0 for successfully delivering the
>   default signals SIGTERM and SIGKILL  otherwise  to  7 if the program
>   was not running.  It is also successful if no signal was specified and
>   no  program  was there for Termination because it is already
>   terminated.

Comment: please see my above edit. When I tried your second suggestion, it kept complaining that [killproc] was not a known program name, so had to change it back to [/bin/kill $pid || return 7]